# Access violation when using glDebugMessageCallback() with SDL?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glew

It seems that I cant use glDebugMessageCallback function, the throws an Access violation error on the very next line of code.

```
ERROR: Exception thrown at 0x0000000000000000 in DEBUG.exe:
0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000.
```

**ErrorHandler.hpp**

```
#define GLCall(x) x;\
    if(isError) __debugbreak();

static bool isError{ false };
namespace ErrorHandler {
    void APIENTRY GLDebugMessageCallback(GLenum source, GLenum type, GLuint id, GLenum severity, GLsizei length, const GLchar* message, const void* userParam);
}
```

**ErrorHandler.cpp**

```
void APIENTRY ErrorHandler::GLDebugMessageCallback(GLenum source, GLenum type, GLuint id, GLenum severity, GLsizei length, const GLchar* message, const void* userParam)
{
    isError = true;
    const char* _source;
    const char* _type;
    const char* _severity;

    switch (source) ...
    switch (type) ...
    switch (severity) ...

    if (_severity != "NOTIFICATION") {
        fprintf(stderr, "OpenGL error [%d]: %s of %s severity, raised from %s: %s\n",
            id, _type, _severity, _source, message);
    }
 }
```

**Game.cpp**

```
Game::Game(const char* title, uint16_t width, uint16_t height)
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) ...

    m_window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if (!m_window) ...
    
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_DEBUG_FLAG);

    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) ...
    m_context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(m_window);
    if (!m_context) ...

    printf("%s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));

#ifdef _DEBUG
    glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
    glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS);
    glDebugMessageCallback(ErrorHandler::GLDebugMessageCallback, 0);
#endif
    m_run();
}
```

I've tried:

1. Moving the glDebugMessageCallback to diffrent lines (directly after initializing glew, after creating context).
2. I've tried to use another function as a callback.
3. I've tried to explicitly set the OpenGL version (4.6.0) and (4.4.0).
4. I've tried to remove any sdl flags (profile flag and version flags).

Everything gives the same result (Access violation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call

```
SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(m_window, m_context);
```

to activate your OpenGL context prior to calling any OpenGL functions. Otherwise the OpenGL functions do not know which context to operate on. Presumably GLFW did that for you automatically, but SDL does not.

I'm not familiar with GLEW, but there's a good chance that `glewInit` also expects a valid context to be active. So the order of operations should be as follows:

```
m_window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
// ...
m_context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(m_window);
SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(m_window, m_context);

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
if (!glewInit()) // ...

printf("%s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
// ...
glDebugMessageCallback(ErrorHandler::GLDebugMessageCallback, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you it worked due the order! + Sorry there was a bug in my code if(!glewInit()) seems to be if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK) instead otherwise it will throw an empty error

Comment: Documentation for `SDL_GL_CreateContext` explicitly states "Create an OpenGL context for an OpenGL window, **and make it current**", so I don't see how that could be an issue. However, `SDL_GL_SetAttribute` should be called before creating a window, not just context (but after `SDL_Init`).

Comment: @keltar you might be right; it must then be all down to the `glewInit` being called before the context was even created.

Comment: @YakovGalka didn't notice at first. Yes that's definitely the problem